# Coredata fetch with NSSortDescriptor by alphabetically and length of property

Tags: core-data, xcode8, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

In myCoredata entity(Persons) I want to fetch fetch all Persons, sorted by the length  of name alphabetically.I have tried the following code

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *lengthSorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“first_name.length" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[lengthSorter, nameSortDescriptor]];
```

But no luck.Is this a completely wrong approach? How am I supposed to do something like this with a CoreData fetch?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it will not work.  Predicates that are used for fetchRequest are turned into mySQL queries so they do not accept everything that is a valid predicate (like predicateWithBlock: for example).

In this case I would suggest adding another column in the table (property in the entity) for `firstNameLength`.  Have ONLY one way that you set the name and also set the nameLength property at the same time (so it doesn't get out of sync). Then you can simply sort by the nameLength property which was pre-calculated.

Also you may not want to use NSString.length because it may not mean what you think it means. Letters that have decoration marks (like "résumé") may have a longer length that you intent.  Also emoji can be 2 or 4 or 8 length strings.  Instead you can count the composed character sequences using `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is add a property with a custom getter to your core data entity's subclass. if your doing a lot of core data I suggest something like mogenerator, or the built in functions for handling entity generation so that you are not over writing your model classes each time you change the model.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=getFirstNameLength) NSUInteger firstNameLength;

-(NSUInteger)getFirstNameLength {
   return [firstName length];
}
```

As long as this method is public in the .h class you will be able to access it just as you would a regular model property in your predicate.

Comment: I tried this code out and I was only able to get it to work with a `NSInMemoryStoreType`.  When I tried it with with a `SQLLiteStoreType` I got an exception : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath firstNameLength not found in entity.  Did you get this work in some way?  Could you share the code?

Comment: interesting, I'm not using the exact code but I'll take a look.

Comment: I was using a custom property for scroll indexes. in a table view. I noticed I added KVO code with self willAccessValueForKey and didAccessValueForKey around my calculation code. I'm puzzled by why your code wouldn't work as a sql store.

Comment: You can use custom properties for scroll indexes and sectionKeyPath because they are calculated in memory after the fetch.  You can't use them for predicates or sort descriptors because they are run on SQL level.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Thought I had a solution for you sorry :-(